# No deploy option QT creator

Tags: linux, ubuntu, qt4, deb

I am trying to make a deb package using QT creator in ubuntu, but I am unable to find the deploy option in Build->Deploy Project ...

I dont know whether there is a difference of QT creator version or is there something I have not installed.. I installed QT creator using synaptic manager of ubuntu.. the same option is being shown in the QT creator I installed in my Red Hat linux..

Is there any other easy way of making a deb package?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to make deb package,

but in my qtcreator there is 
`Build->Deploy All` but not `Build->Deploy Project.`

ps:my os is archlinux and i install qtcreator by pacman